# How to handle ' java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider' error i Android studio

Tags: android

I am trying to open a pdf file from firebase storage to my app.
This is my code for getting file Url.

```
StorageReference fileref=mStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(selectedItem.getFileUrl());
String fileref_string=fileref.toString();
Uri file_uri=Uri.parse(fileref_string);
```

But it is showing this error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: gs://funn-30a97.appspot.com/uploads/1531599733740.pdf

How to deal with this?

code for uploading file:
mFileUri is url of file from device.

```
if (mFileUri != null) {
        StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(mFileUri));
        fileReference.putFile(mFileUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                            }
                        }, 5000);
                        Toast.makeText(upload.this, "Upload Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Uploading uploading = new Uploading(mEditTextFileName.getText().toString().trim(), taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                        String uploadId = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                        mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(uploading);


                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(upload.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                        mProgressBar.setProgress((int) progress);
                    }
                });
```

Uploading Class:

```
public class Uploading {
private String mname;
private String mfileUrl;
private String mKey;

public Uploading() {

}

public Uploading(String name, String fileUrl) {
    if (name.trim().equals("")) {
        name = "no name";
    }
    mname = name;
    mfileUrl = fileUrl;
}

public String getName() {
    return mname;
}

public void setName(String Name) {
    mname = Name;
}

public String getFileUrl() {
    return mfileUrl;
}

public void setfileUrl(String url) {
    mfileUrl = url;
}

@Exclude
public String getKey() {
    return mKey;
}

@Exclude
public void setKey(String key) {
    mKey = key;
}
```

}

Comment: Which code is trying to find a file?

Comment: I just wanted file url so that I can view file from that

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way of doing this. You shouldn't call `toString()` on your `StorageReference` object.

Try this:

```
    if (fileref.getPath().length() != 0) {
        fileref.getDownloadUrl()
               .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                       // Now you have the Uri of your file
                   }
               });
    }
```

Good luck!

Comment: Gil, above code is  giving same error. And also I don't want to download file just wanted file url so that I can read file from that.

Comment: 1. The code above does not download the file, but merely provides a Uri, as you wanted. You can use that Uri to read the file.
2. Please provide the code in which you upload the file. It may be that your error comes from this part:
StorageReference fileref=mStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(selectedItem.getFileUrl());